# Principio de sustitución de Liskov

Tags: poo, diseño

¿En que casos se esta violando el principio de sustitución de Liskov cuando se usa una herencia? ¿Cuando la clase heredada tiene una pre condición mas restrictiva que la clase padre y una post condición mas permisiva en uno de sus constructores o métodos. cuando el comportamiento es diferente al de la clase padre?

Answer (score 4):

Primero

## Algunas definiciones

En palabras de la Wikipedia, el [Principio de sustitución de Liskov](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principio_de_sustituci%C3%B3n_de_Liskov) puede definirse como:

> Cada clase que hereda de otra puede usarse como su padre sin necesidad de conocer las diferencias entre ellas

Esto impone una serie de reglas a la herencia. Las más obvias son las que tienen que ver con las *firmas* de los métodos, y son reforzadas por prácticamente todos los lenguajes modernos, así que no hace falta hablar mucho de ellas.

Liskov también impone algunas reglas en el comportamiento de los objetos (su contrato). En general, estas reglas no pueden ser verificadas por el compilador, así que no hay manera de garantizarlas, sin embargo, son muy útiles en el razonamiento del diseño de una jerarquía de clases.

Estas reglas son:

- Las pre condiciones no pueden ser más fuertes en el subtipo.
- Las post condiciones no pueden ser más débiles en el subtipo.
- Las invariantes de clase deben ser honradas y preservadas en el subtipo.
- La Regla de la Historia. Dado que los objetos pueden modificarse sólo a través de sus métodos, y que los subtipos pueden introducir métodos que no están presentes en el supertipo, podría introducirse un cambio de estado que no está permitido en el supertipo. La Regla de la Historia lo prohíbe.

Entendiendo la [Regla de la Historia](https://github.com/delucas/notas/blob/master/01_objetos/03_solid/03_lsp.md)

> La Regla de la Historia tiene que ver con las expectativas que los clientes de nuestras clases tienen sobre las mismas. Si se establecen ciertos criterios de funcionamiento para los supertipos, al ser los subtipos sustitutos válidos de los mismos podríamos incurrir en comportamientos inesperados.
>
> Por ejemplo, si existiera un `PuntoMutable` (que puede cambiar) como subtipo de `PuntoInmutable` (que no puede cambiar) estamos incurriendo en una falta a las expectativas de los clientes de nuestras clases: no se espera que cambie un PuntoMutable

Ahora si

## Respondiendo la pregunta

> ¿En que casos se esta violando el principio de sustitución de Liskov cuando se usa una herencia?

Los ejemplos típicos son:

- El ya mencionado `PuntoMutable` que hereda de `PuntoInmutable`, que viola la regla de la historia.
- Heredar un `Cuadrado` de un `Rectángulo`. Asumiendo que existen métodos `set` para el `ancho` y `alto`. Si un cuadrado fuera utilizado en el contexto dónde se espera un rectángulo, puede ocurrir un comportamiento inesperado ya que las dimensiones de un cuadrado no pueden (y no debieran) modificarse de manera independiente. Este problema no puede arreglarse fácilmente. Si modificamos los métodos `set` de la clase `Cuadrado` para que preserven su invariante (i.e. mantener la igualdad de sus dimensiones), entonces estos métodos debilitarían (violarían) las post condiciones de los métodos `set` del rectángulo, que establecen que las dimensiones pueden cambiarse de manera independiente. Las violaciones como esta al *PSL* (o *LSP* por sus siglas en inglés) pueden o no ser un problema en la práctica, dependiendo de las post condiciones o invariantes que se esperan realmente en el código que utiliza las clases que violan el *LSP*.

La mutabilidad es un factor clave aquí. Si `Cuadrado` y `Rectángulo` tienen solamente métodos `get` (i.e. son inmutables), entonces no habría violación al *LSP*.

Comment: A ver si lo he entendido, se viola este principio si: un objeto que has invocado que no sabes si es de la clase padre o la derivada no se comporta como se espera en la implementación de la clase padre. Si en la clase derivada tienes un método sin implementar de la clase padre(por un mal diseño). Controlar que la clase derivada sea menos restrictiva que su padre ya que si fuese al contrario no podría  ejecutar el método de la derivada al ser más restrictiva que la de la base.

Comment: No es que no sepas si es de la clase padre o de la derivada. La idea general (y por eso se llama principio de sustitución) es que el código que _trabaja_ con un objeto nunca sabe si el objeto en realidad es de la clase declarada (_padre_) o de cualquier clase que herede de ella. Tampoco se trata de la implementación en si, como ya he mencionado, esta regla es útil en el razonamiento de la jerarquía, pero no hay forma práctica de reforzarla, y en ocasiones violarla no acarrea problemas.

Comment: Así, no lo plantearía como si _en la clase derivada tienes un método sin implementar de la clase padre_, sino más bien es si la clase derivada se comporta de una manera que no es esperada o aceptable para el padre. Hablando de métodos, te recuerdo que para un código particular X, generalmente solo son visibles los métodos que existen en la clase declarada para la variable o parámetro en cuestión, y por tanto no puede invocar métodos de las clases derivadas (a menos que se use reflexión u otras técnicas que no vienen al caso para este análisis).

Comment: Con _un objeto que has invocado que no sabes si es de la clase padre o la derivada y no se comporta como la padre_, quería decir que en el caso de ejemplo del rectángulo y el cuadrado, Si lo que vas a recibir es un rectángulo por parámetro, pero recibes un cuadrado y no se comporta como lo que esperabas por parámetro (en este caso el rectángulo) estas violando el principio ¿no?

Comment: No lo estás violando tu, lo está violando el autor de la clase _Cuadrado_